# How to get data from web page every hour using alarm manager in android?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am making an app that needs to get data from an html element in a web page and send a notification that includes the data every hour when the app isn't running. To do this, I am using an `AlarmManager`. in my `AlarmReceiver` class I then tried using JSoup to connect to the website.

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intentt) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This gave me exception `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

So I then tried this solution:

```
    final WebView w = new WebView(context);
    w.loadUrl(URL);
    WebSettings webSettings = w.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            w.evaluateJavascript("(function() { return document.getElementById('app_notification_id').innerHTML;})()", new ValueCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
                  ...
```

This time i saw in the debugger that the code inside the `OnPageFinished` wasn't even executed, although when I try it inside `MainActivity` when the app is active and running this code works fine.

How can I achieve my goal? Is there another approach that works or do I have a mistake in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onReceive()` method of `BroadcastReceiver` is called on the main application thread, and you should **not do disk I/O or network I/O** on the main application thread. That's why you got `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Move that HTTP code into another `IntentService`, and call -

> startService(intentService)

on `onReceive()` method of `BroadcastReceiver`.

Also You cannot add `WebView` in receiver because it requires activity reference as you are adding it from only context reference. Just apply above solution.

Comment: i tried what you said          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intentt) { Intent intent=new Intent(context,GetNotiDataService.class); context.startService(intent); }   this didnt do anything for some reason

Comment: you have to define this service in Manifest? Have you added it?

Comment: i got another question. like you said when i add this line in the IntentService         final WebView w = new WebView(getApplication());
my app crashes. so my question is do you know how i can get the data from the element if i cant use a webview? Jsoup doesnt work either because the element i need is changed after the page has loaded in other words it isnt created with html and jsoup is an html parser. hope i am understandable :)

Comment: You have to parse HTML in `AsyncTask` either using JSOUP or any other HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JobScheduler instead of AlarmManager. AlarmManager has been outdated. Look at the link for more information.

https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution for my problem. I was able to create a new webview and use OnPageFinished which is what i was trying to achieve by adding these lines to the code

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
try {
    handler.post(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final WebView w = new WebView(context);
                    w.loadUrl(url);
                    WebSettings webSettings = w.getSettings();
                    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                    webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
                    w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                            w.evaluateJavascript("(function() { return document.getElementById('app_notification_id').innerHTML;})()", new ValueCallback<String>() {
                                ...
```

Comment: if for some reason this solution is not a good one please tell me in the comments